# Is it possible to have multiple Eclipse installs on one computer?

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to have multiple Eclipse installs on one computer? To make myself more clear, does Eclipse create any local settings files that other installs would mistake for their own?

Comment: Why should you install Eclipse 29 times?!

Comment: @GaryKlasen - I mean if I wanted a install for Java development and then an install for C++ stuff, is that possible?

Comment: see @Chris Gerken. Yes, it is. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I do Eclipse plug-in development, so I have 9 Eclipses installed, from 3.2 to 4.2

I put each Eclipse in a separate directory like this.

```
C:
    eclipse-3.6 RCP
    eclipse-4.2 Java
    eclipse-4.2 RCP
```

I unzip the Eclipse package to the appropriate sub-directory.

I use Windows, so I create a shortcut for the Eclipse executable modules (eclipse.exe).

**24 September 2015 update based on the comments:**

I have a separate workspace for each of my Eclipse instances.  When I want to upgrade one of my workspaces to a newer Eclipse, I do the following:

1. Unzip the newer Eclipse to a eclipse- directory.  My most recent version now is Eclipse Luna (4.4.2).
2. Create a new workspace.
3. Carefully, one Java project at a time, **copy** the project code from the old workspace to the new workspace.  Test and make sure **everything** in the Java project works.
4. Keep the old workspace as a backup for at least 6 months.

If you work on Eclipse plug-ins, step 3 is a bit different.

3. Create a new Eclipse plug-in.  Carefully copy your Eclipse plug-in code from the old Eclipse plug-in to the new Eclipse plug-in.  Test as you reconstruct your Eclipse plug-in.  This is as painful as it reads, which is why I don't upgrade my Eclipse plug-ins too often.

Comment: Can you [keep your markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757961/) across your different installations without problem?

Comment: @GizMecano: Yes.  You have to have different workspaces for each of your eclipse versions.

Comment: So, it's impossible to use the same workspace (containing a set of markers) through different installations: does it mean that markers are formatted depending of Eclipse version?

Comment: @GizMecano: It is possible to upgrade an older workspace with a newer Eclipse.  I don't recommend upgrading your workspaces.  I don't know, but I suspect that marker formats can change with newer versions of Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer seems to fit with [the last comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757961/multiple-eclipse-installations-and-types-of-markers#comment53365699_32758155) I have received to my query.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc nice answer, I noticed that eclipse uses {user.home}/.eclipse and .p2 folders. And those folders will be shared between all eclipse versions. I dont like this setup and wonder if you have any feedback? I have managed to let eclipse use another .eclipse folder by adding osgi.configuration.area and eclipse.p2.data.area but there are also some equinox.p2 settings (edits in eclipse.ini). And I think this is not so easy, I think still there is some hardcoded lines that wants to use the default .p2 folder. Any ideas on how having multiple versions totally isolated from each other??

Comment: @MrSimpleMind: I wrote this answer a few versions of Eclipse ago.  I'm still using Eclipse Kepler for my Java work, so I'm not familiar with the installation of the latest versions.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc ok maybe I send a question instead. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Eclipse support multiple installs. By default Eclipse installs in one directory with all the options, configs, etc. in different subdirectories. The only problem would be with choosing proper Eclipse install for given project (e.g. opening C++ project in Eclipse for php without C++ components).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have multiple installs.  Most settings are kept in the workspace's .metadata directory.  There may be some other settings stored back in the install directory.  I've never heard of any settings being saved off anywhere else.