# Multiple Eclipse installations and types of markers

Tags: eclipse

I know that it's possible [to have multiple Eclipse installations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764625/) on the same computer or [to use several workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053887/) with a single installation, but I wonder if different versions might share the same markers.

Indeed, I currently use the 4.3 Kepler version, but I would be interested in testing some later versions (such as 4.5 Mars) at the same time, but without risking of overwriting or losing all bookmarks, tasks and other types of markers which are useful for my current projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markers are stored in the `.metadata` folder of the workspace. So if you use a different workspace there will not be any problem.

Comment: So, if a workspace seems to be depending of the version of Eclipse, it is impossible to use the same markers from a unique workspace across different installations. I could open a same project with two different versions, but I couldn't use bookmarks or tasks from a version into another one. Right?

Comment: Markers will carry over from an older version, but the new version of Eclipse may change the workspace metadata so that you can't go back.

Comment: Thank you. Perfect addition to my question.